# SAS: Adding a column from one dataset to another without a key

Tags: sas, dataset, data-manipulation

Dataset 1 is like this:

```
A     B     C 
1     2     3
7     8     9
```

Dataset 2 is like this:

```
D     E     F
4     5     6
```

I would like to combine both datasets like so:

```
A     B     C     D     E     F
1     2     3     4     5     6
7     8     9     4     5     6
```

Is there a way to do this in SAS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data data3;
   set data1;
   if _n_ eq 1 then set data2;
   run;
```

The works because variables that come from SET statement(s) are not initialized to missing at the top of the data step loop.